# ag-grid: none of the client side tree data examples working

Tags: angular, ag-grid, client-side

I have tried all of the client-side tree data examples from ag-grid.com in Angular 11.2.9 and none of them are working. When you run them directly from their site, they all work, but when you copy the source into your local environment, none of them are working.

The examples source codes are in the link below:

```
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/tree-data/
```

When I run ng serve, nothing shows up on the browser.  In the source, I see a lot of divs with ag-grid related classes, ag-body-* and it appears there are rows being occupied, except nothing is visible.

There are no error messages in the dev console.

Does anyone have any working examples of client-side tree data that actually shows on a browser?
thanks

Comment: do you have any code to show? Stackblitz? btw this is `enterprise` feature make sure you also have imported ag-grid-enterprise

Comment: there are a few source codes in the link that I posted.  It appears to be working when I click their link, but when I copy their source into my angular environment, nothing is visible on the browser.  We do have a license for the enterprise version.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your web dev console?

Comment: I did not get any errors in the dev console.  I added a few console.log statements and they are being triggered and I see the logging messages in the console.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I figured it out.  ag-grid example was using 100% as height.  I changed it to a fixed value ... 500px and now it is showing.